# Find the position of ball on the $2017^{th}$ step

Tags: combinatorics

$10$ people are seating on chairs around a circular table. These chairs are marked $0,1,2,.....9$ in a clockwise manner.

There is a ball on the man’s hand who is seated on $0$-marked chair, and the ball will be passed from one man to another in clockwise manner. 
In first step, the ball goes to $1$-marked chair with $1^1$ turn. In second step, from there, the ball goes to $5$-marked chair with $2^2$ turns. In third step, the ball goes to $2$-marked chair by $3^3$ turns from $5$-marked chair.
By this means, in which chair the ball will be right after the $2017$<sup>th</sup> step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to is just sum up $1^1+2^2+3^3+....+2017^{2017}$ and find the remainder on dividing it by $10$. That will give you the answer. Now as we are going to divide by $10$ and need just the remainder we just find the unit places of these numbers.

We first write down some unit places from $1$ to $10$ we get
$$(1,4,7,6,5,6,3,6,9,0)$$ . Now writing the unit places of $11$ to $20$ $$(1,6,3,6,5,6,7,4,9,0)$$. Now writing for $21$ to $30$ we get unit places as $$(1,4,7,6,5,6,3,6,9,0)$$.Did you notice the pattern? 
Also sum of all unit places of each group of $10$ is $47.$

Hence up-to $2010$ the sum of unit places will be $201* 47.$ 
Now from $2011$ to $2017$ the unit places are $(1,6,3,6,5,6,7)$ whose sum is $34$. Now we need to find the remainder on dividing $201*47+34$ by 10.

Hence our answer will be the remainder obtained on dividing this number(which equals $9481$) by $10$.

Note that finding these unit places is easy using the cyclicity  of each number and it's exponents.

Hence the answer to the question is $\mathbf 1$.

Comment: You've made a mistake in the unit places $11$ to $20$.

Comment: @Myridium Where? Can you please tell where the mistake actually is

Comment: Sorry, I thought you would spot it right away. Shouldn't it be the same sequence of numbers as above and below? Actually wait, upon calculation, shouldn't they all be $(1,4,9,6,5,6,9,4,1,0)$?

Comment: @Myridium its $n^n$ and not $n^2$

Comment: Ah okay sorry :)

Comment: Samjoe is right. The unit places you posted could have been correct if it was $n^2$ and not $n^n$

Comment: Never mind :) The solution is good!

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to find the remainder of $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2017} k^k$ modulo $10$. For each integer $k \geqslant 0$,\begin{gather*}
(10k + 1)^{10k + 1} \equiv 1^{10k + 1} = 1, \quad (10k + 9)^{10k + 9} \equiv (-1)^{10k + 9} = -1, \pmod{10}\\
(10k + 10)^{10k + 10} \equiv 0 \pmod{10}.
\end{gather*}
Because\begin{gather*}
(10k + 4)^{10k + 4} \equiv 0, \quad (10k + 5)^{10k + 2} \equiv 1, \quad (10k + 6)^{10k + 6} \equiv 1, \pmod{2}\\
(10k + 4)^{10k + 4} \equiv (-1)^{10k + 4} \equiv 1, \quad (10k + 6)^{10k + 6} \equiv 1^{10k + 6} \equiv 1, \pmod{5}\\
\quad (10k + 5)^{10k + 2} \equiv 0, \pmod{5}
\end{gather*}
by Chinese remainder theorem,$$
(10k + 4)^{10k + 4} \equiv 6, \quad (10k + 5)^{10k + 2} \equiv 5, \quad (10k + 6)^{10k + 6} \equiv 6. \pmod{10}
$$
Now,\begin{gather*}
(10k + 2)^{10k + 2} \equiv 0, \quad (10k + 8)^{10k + 8} \equiv 0, \pmod{2}\\
(10k + 3)^{10k + 3} \equiv 1, \quad (10k + 7)^{10k + 7} \equiv 1. \pmod{2}
\end{gather*}
Note that $m^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ for $m = 2, 3, 7, 8$ by Fermat's little theorem. If $k = 2k_0 + 1$ is an odd integer,\begin{gather*}
(10k + 2)^{10k + 2} \equiv 2^{10k + 2} = 2^{20k_0 + 12} \equiv 1 \pmod{5},\\
(10k + 3)^{10k + 3} \equiv 3^{10k + 3} = 3^{20k_0 + 13} \equiv 3 \pmod{5},\\
(10k + 7)^{10k + 7} \equiv 7^{10k + 7} = 7^{20k_0 + 17} \equiv 2 \pmod{5},\\
(10k + 8)^{10k + 8} \equiv 8^{10k + 8} = 8^{20k_0 + 18} \equiv 4 \pmod{5},
\end{gather*}
by Chinese remainder theorem,\begin{gather*}
(10k + 2)^{10k + 2} \equiv 6, \quad (10k + 3)^{10k + 3} \equiv 3, \pmod{10}\\
(10k + 7)^{10k + 7} \equiv 7, \quad (10k + 8)^{10k + 8} \equiv 4. \pmod{10}
\end{gather*}
If $k = 2k_0$ is an even integer,\begin{gather*}
(10k + 2)^{10k + 2} \equiv 2^{10k + 2} = 2^{20k_0 + 2} \equiv 4 \pmod{5},\\
(10k + 3)^{10k + 3} \equiv 3^{10k + 3} = 3^{20k_0 + 3} \equiv 2 \pmod{5},\\
(10k + 7)^{10k + 7} \equiv 7^{10k + 7} = 7^{20k_0 + 7} \equiv 3 \pmod{5},\\
(10k + 8)^{10k + 8} \equiv 8^{10k + 8} = 8^{20k_0 + 8} \equiv 1 \pmod{5},
\end{gather*}
by Chinese remainder theorem,\begin{gather*}
(10k + 2)^{10k + 2} \equiv 4, \quad (10k + 3)^{10k + 3} \equiv 7, \pmod{10}\\
(10k + 7)^{10k + 7} \equiv 3, \quad (10k + 8)^{10k + 8} \equiv 6. \pmod{10}
\end{gather*}
Therefore, for each integer $k \geqslant 0$,$$
\sum_{j = 10k + 1}^{10k + 10} j^j \equiv 7 \pmod{10}.
$$
So$$
\sum_{j = 1}^{2017} j^j \equiv 7 \times 201 + \sum_{j = 2011}^{2017} j^j \equiv 7 + (1 + 1 + 3 + 6 + 5 + 6 + 2) \equiv 1 \pmod{10}.
$$

Comment: It's a good solution with a bit more insight using the modular arithmetic on the similar solution posted by me.